Using v-model and @input together
I have a select input in vue. And everytime i select something i need to do condition checking. I need to check the data used in v-model. My question is, is the data updated before the input function is executed? V-model also uses :value and @input. But here i add a custom @input. Here's an example
<template>

  <select v-model="val" @input="handleInput">

    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>

    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>

  </select>

</template>


<script>

export default {

  data() {

    return {

      val: null // initial value

    }

  },

  methods: {

    handleInput() {

      if (this.val === "option1") {

//do something

}

    }

  }

}

</script>


Is the value null here or updated and set to the value of select input?
I did a similar example once and got null. Then recently i tested a new code and it worked. So i'm confused. I use version 2.6.11 by the way.

If you need a custom @input, use :value instead of v-model
<select :value="val" @input="handleInput"></select>



Just use the event change and trigger your method everytime your select will be changed. Define your val as empty string if null is not working.
<template>
  <select v-model="val" @change="doStuff()">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  </select>
</template>

You can also use dynamic options like this. Just define your array in your script and reference at it in your template - this will help you when you dynamically change your array or get data from an api e.g..
<template>
  <select v-model="val" @change="doStuff()">
    <option v-for="option in optionArray" :key="option.value" :value="option.value">
      {{ option.label }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      val: "",
      optionArray: [
        { "value": 1, "label": "Option 1" }
        { "value": 2, "label": "Option 2" }
      ]
    }
  }
</script>

